# Compute requirements for NN Training vs Deployed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand the compute requirements for deploying a NN vs the compute requirements for training.

I have searched and all the references I have found talk to the training demand.

I am expecting but not finding that the demand does not vary significantly for one training event vs one test event.

I am trying to understand if it is feasible for a trained model to be deployed to say a mobile phone that is offline.

As I understand it, in most use cases, the mobile phone will gather and submit the input data that is then sent to the central server(example) that computes and returns the result.

Assuming something like image analysis, is this feasible to be deployed pre-trained to some low compute power device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible deploy pre-trained model to cell phone. The difference between production & training is quite big because:

1. Usually you process one image in deployed model vs batch of images in training time
2. You can optimize model in several ways for production:

   - exclude some layers e.g. dropout, batch normalization
   - quantize model (replace float by int8)
   - run model on cell phone GPU, DSP (see [Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine SDK](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forums/software/snapdragon-npe-sdk))